# What would be the expected approximate ROD when descending at 250 kt IAS using LVL CHG at 10,000 ft, assuming a GW of 60t?

Tags: boeing-737, descent

The question refers to a B737NG but I suppose most similarly sized airliners would show a similar ROD under the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

A descent at idle power and 250 knots yields about 1,500 feet per minute in the 737. Perhaps a bit less in the Max (maybe 1,300 - 1,400 fpm) with its lower drag profile, and a bit more (like 1,600 fpm) in a Classic.

Source: personal experience flying 737's.